# Inferring Observable Value type using TypeScript Awaited<T> Utility Type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics, nest

I was working on NestJS, at some parts of the applications. I was using the observable and wanted to get the type of value by inferring the type dynamically present in the observable similar to `Awaited<T>` for promise.

I tried to create a generic type that takes the observable type and resolves the value type, see below:
`type AwaitedObservable<T> = T extends Observable<infer R>? AwaitedObservable<R>: T;`

But this does not work, the compiler yells at me and shows an error.
I have no idea why is this not working, any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Your type is definetely correct. What kind of error do you have ?

Comment: It shows this error.  
                                                                                                        
   
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<number[]>> | ((value: number[]) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(res: AwaitedObservable<typeof this.observable1>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer<number[]>> | ((value: number[]) => void) | undefined'.

Comment: Here is the sample reproduced in angular
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-f4yzcm?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I guess a better question would be why do you need this in the first place? I see that you used this in the subscribe, but the type should be inferred by typescript there. I'd rather check why the type isn't inferred all the way till there because you may have other issues in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `toArray` you're converting your `Observable<number>` into `Observable<number[]>`.

This is why your compiler is complaining.

Your `AwaitedObservable` type is fine.

Comment: How could i infer the type produced from the last operator of my observable ?

Comment: Let the inference do its job, just don't type it !